# How to open pdf file in new tab in asp.net(vb)?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, openpdf

I want to show my pdf file in new tab when I click the button of gridview. How can I display? Please someone help me .
This is my code.

```
'my gridview button click event
 Protected Sub btnDisplay_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
        Dim grdrow As GridViewRow = CType((CType(sender, Button)).NamingContainer, GridViewRow)

        'I save pdf with datetime but showing file name without datetime on screen so I need to 
         'combine again when I need to open the file from upload folder

        Dim dtime As DateTime = grdrow.Cells(2).Text 
        Dim fname As String = lblFileName.Text.Split(".").First + "_" + 
                              dtime.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmss") + ".pdf"

        Dim FilePath As String = Server.MapPath("~/uploads/" & fname)



        Dim User As WebClient = New WebClient()
        Dim FileBuffer As Byte() = User.DownloadData(FilePath)

        If FileBuffer IsNot Nothing Then
            Response.ContentType = "application/pdf"
            Response.AddHeader("content-length", FileBuffer.Length.ToString())
            Response.BinaryWrite(FileBuffer)
        End If
    End Sub
```

--Edit--
I got some idea and it did work for me.
I added some script to open new tab.

html,gridview

```
//javascript
<script type="text/javascript">
        function openInNewTab() {
            window.document.forms[0].target = '_blank';
            setTimeout(function () { window.document.forms[0].target = ''; }, 0);
        }
</script>

<asp:BoundField DataField="FileName" HeaderText="Filename" ItemStyle-Width="200" HtmlEncode="false"><ItemStyle Width="200px"></ItemStyle></asp:BoundField>
<asp:BoundField DataField="Process" HeaderText="Process" ItemStyle-Width="200" HtmlEncode="false"><ItemStyle Width="200px"></ItemStyle></asp:BoundField>
<asp:TemplateField ItemStyle-Width="80px" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center">
                        <ItemTemplate>                
                            <asp:Button ID="btnDisplay" runat="server" Text="Display" OnClick="btnDisplay_Click" OnClientClick="openInNewTab();" Visible='<%# If(Eval("Process").ToString() = "Uploaded", True, False) %>'></asp:Button>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
```

Main.aspx

```
Protected Sub btnDisplay_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)

        Dim grdrow As GridViewRow = CType((CType(sender, Button)).NamingContainer, GridViewRow)
        Dim fname As String = grdrow.Cells(2).Text 

        'pdf Display
        Session("pdfname") = fname
        Response.Redirect("GeneratePDF.aspx")

    End Sub
```

GeneratePDF.aspx

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div style ="Display: Inline-block;float: left;">
        <asp:Literal ID="ltEmbed" runat="server" />
    </div>
    </form>
```

GeneratePDF.aspx.vb

```
Dim pdf_name As String
    Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        Page.Title = "PDF DISPLAY"
        pdf_name = Session("pdfname")
        Dim embed As String = "<object data=""{0}"" type=""application/pdf"" width=""2000px"" height=""1000px"">"
        embed += "If you are unable to view file, you can download from <a href = ""{0}"">here</a>"
        embed += " or download <a target = ""_blank"" href = ""http://get.adobe.com/reader/"">Adobe PDF Reader</a> to view the file."
        embed += "</object>"
        ltEmbed.Text = String.Format(embed, ResolveUrl("~/uploads/" + pdf_name))

    End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

First use hyperlink instead of Button and make target =_blank. Then on Page Load of new aspx write code for generating PDF.

```
'HTML CODE

<asp:HyperLink ID="btnDisplay" runat="server" Text="Open PDF"  Target ="_blank" NavigateUrl="~/WBP/GeneratePDF.aspx"></asp:HyperLink>


'SERVER CODE


Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) 
Handles Me.Load
    
        Dim dtime As DateTime = DateTime.Now.ToString()

        Dim fname As String = "pdffile_" +
                          dtime.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmss") + ".pdf"
        Dim FilePath As String = Server.MapPath("writereaddata/" & fname)

        Dim User As WebClient = New WebClient()


        HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "application/pdf"


        HttpContext.Current.Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache)

        Dim sw As New StringWriter()
        Dim hw As New HtmlTextWriter(sw)
        Dim pdfDoc As New Document(PageSize.A4, 10, 10, 8, 2)

        Dim htmlparser As New HTMLWorker(pdfDoc)
        PdfWriter.GetInstance(pdfDoc, HttpContext.Current.Response.OutputStream)
        Dim sr As New StringReader(sw.ToString())

        pdfDoc.Open()
        Dim pthd As Paragraph = New Paragraph("WELCOME TO PDF FILE", New Font(Font.TIMES_ROMAN, 11, Font.BOLD, Color.BLACK))
        pdfDoc.Add(pthd)
        htmlparser.Parse(sr)
        pdfDoc.Close()

        HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(pdfDoc)

        HttpContext.Current.Response.End()

End Sub
```

Comment: thz you for your answer. I am using vs 2019 and some code didn't work well for me. May be I am new for this. I did found some way to open new tab. So I edited my question and added the code that is worked for me. Thz you again.

Answer (score 0):

i think you are missing something, add Response.End() at the end of the if statement

```
 If FileBuffer IsNot Nothing Then
        Response.ContentType = "application/pdf"
        Response.AddHeader("content-length", FileBuffer.Length.ToString())
        Response.BinaryWrite(FileBuffer)
        Response.End()
    End If
```

if it doesnt work, there must be an issue on the Html

Comment: Lorenzo, thz for your answer. I added Response.End( ) but still can't open new tab. I also edited my question to add my html code.

Comment: @Chang nice! Check the answer of MrinmoyeeG. It should work for you. If it doesnt work, remember that you can add a pdf reader and you can use  `<asp:LinkButton>` for it. You can find a valid example here: https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/PDF-Viewer-ASPNet-Embed-PDF-file-on-Web-Page-in-ASPNet-using-C-and-VBNet.aspx

Comment: Thanks! I got the idea when I saw your example and it did work.